# Expectation of Function of Random Variable is Constant

Tags: probability, expected-value

My intuition tells me that for r.v. $X$, there exists no function $f$ such that E $f(X) = c$, a constant, other than the constant function. Is that correct and if so is there a result that shows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean for any random variable $X$, then only a constant function can do, and $f(X)\equiv c$ is in fact no more random.

If you mean for a given random variable $X$, then *every* function will do, as the expectation of a distribution is a constant (provided it exists).

Comment: In the second case, what if I want the expectation of a function of a given rv $X$ to equal a fixed constant for any given $X$? Then is the constant function equal to the fixed constant the only suitable function?

Comment: @user955857: "for any given $X$" is the first case. Pay attention.